# Can't select fields from AgentWork using APEX code in managed package

Tags: apex, managed-package, unmanaged-package, omnichannel

I am trying to run APEX code from **managed package** to retrieve fields from AgentWork table. 
My statement is

```
SELECT ActiveTime FROM AgentWork WHERE id = '0BzB000000098N4'
```

I get back the following result :

"No such column 'ActiveTime' on entity 'AgentWork'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."

When I try to run **the same statement** from Developer Console - it works fine.
The only difference that I could think of is that this is managed code versus unmanaged.

BUT this statement works if I try to retrieve by id

So this would work

```
SELECT id FROM AgentWork WHERE id = '0BzB000000098N4'
```

Does anybody have an explanation for this problem ? Does anybody has a solution to this problem?

Comment: What's the API version of your apex class in the managed package?

Comment: open cti version is 38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is class API version. In order to compile with that field Class has to be updated to API 37.0 to see it. Tried on TestRunResultId on ApexTestQueueItem - does not compile on API 36, works on API 37.

See link below image for release notes.
[image]

[Win 16 Release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_api_objects_changed.htm)